# disable statement not killing other block in the fork statement

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is the code

```
module aks();

  initial begin
     rad temp ;
     temp = new;
     temp.fork_ll();

   end
endmodule
```

//This is Class Which is used in above module

```
class rad;
 task fork_ll();
     fork
          begin:MYLOOP
             $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
             disable SECOND;//I expected it should kill the SECOND BLOCk 
          end:MYLOOP
          begin:SECOND
               $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
               #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
          end:SECOND
     join
  endtask
endclass
```

I Expected the Output As

```
I AM HERE
STEP 2
```

But Actually i am getting Output as

```
0  $unit_0x5d440f27.rad.fork_ll.MYLOOP:I AM HERE 
           0  $unit_0x5d440f27.rad.fork_ll.SECOND:STEP 2 
       10000  $unit_0x5d440f27.rad.fork_ll.SECOND:STEP3
```

Why disable SECOND is Not Killed the SECOND block of statement

Answer (score 2):

Execution order can be non-deterministic (within a scheduling region). Every simulator I have every used execute based on execution order and compiling order.

Verilog executes all code procedurally. It appears (mostly) concurrent because the Verilog scheduler multi-threads each procedural block. One procedural process will run at a time and will complete the procedure unless it is suspended with a blocking statement (`#`, `@`, `wait`).

In your case, `MYLOOP` finished before `SECOND` could ever start. There is nothing for `disable` to disable.

Here are some options:

Disable the task itself (`SECOND` will never start):

```
task fork_ll();
  fork
    begin : MYLOOP
      $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
      disable fork_ll;
    end
    begin : SECOND
      $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
      #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
    end
 join
 endtask
```

> I AM HERE

Momentarily suspend `MYLOOP` with a `#0` (use cautiously, `#0` has is own race condition issues):

```
task fork_ll();
  fork
    begin : MYLOOP
      $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
      #0; // let other procedural blocks start, then continue
      disable SECOND; //
    end
    begin : SECOND
      $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
      #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
    end
 join
 endtask
```

> I AM HERE
>   STEP 2

Use an event trigger:

```
task fork_ll();
  event e;
  fork
    begin : MYLOOP
      $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
      @(e); // let other procedural blocks start
      disable SECOND; //
    end
    begin : SECOND
      ->e; // unblock FIRST, SECOND is still active
      $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
      // ->e; // event trigger could be here too
      #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
    end
 join
 endtask
```

> I AM HERE
>   STEP 2

Working examples [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/DYB)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) (section 9.6.2 - Disable Statement):

> If the block is not currently executing, the disable has no effect.

This code can solve your problem:

```
task fork_ll();
  fork
    begin
      $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
      #10;
    end
    begin
      $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
      #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
    end
 join_any
 disable fork;
 endtask
```

Another solution:

```
task fork_ll();
  fork
    begin: FIRST
      $display("%t  %M:I AM HERE ",$time);
      #1 disable SECOND;
    end
    begin: SECOND
      $display("%t  %M:STEP 2 ",$time);
      #10us $display("%t  %M:STEP3 ",$time);
    end
    join_any
 endtask
```

So, the output will be:

```
IAM HERE
STEP 2
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, maybe when the first block is executing the statement disable does not see that there is a SECOND block in the scope. If I change the order of the blocks I can remove the delay #1 and the code will work as expected.